# Android: Download font typeface and use in app

Tags: android, parse-platform, download, typeface

I am making a drawing app in which user can inflate text boxes. I would like to have a wide variety of fonts for the text boxes, however

1. putting all the fonts into the asset folder, the initial apk size will be enormous and unnecessary since users maybe prefer to use some of the specific fonts only
2. as further development of the app, I would like to continue adding fonts file for the users, and hence is tended to put the file to online database, eg Parse, if there are any updates, and let users to download their preferred fonts if needed.

### Question:

Basically I know the way for downloading imagefiles from Parse and inflating such downloaded images into Gridview, and hence it should also be possible to put the ttf font type to parse and download as ParseObject in a similar way.

However, is it possible that after downloaded, such downloaded font file be saved and used (populate into the arraylist of font choice)?

Just would like to obtain some of the directions (and samples). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's pretty straightforward as long as you know how to set a custom font to a `TextView` or to an `EditText.

As soon as you obtain your custom font (in whatever way you want to) just save it to the storage of the device and create a custom `Typeface` object (which you can then use to set this custom font to your `TextView` or `EditText`).

It should be something like this (just a simple example):

```
TextView customFontTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_custom_font);
EditText customFontEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_custom_font);

String pathToTTFFile = "...";
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromFile(pathToTTFFile);

customFontTextView.setTypeface(customTypeface);
customFontEditText.setTypeface(customTypeface);
```

and thats it.